# PowerShell: Add a new blank line after every 50 words on several text files

Tags: powershell, shell, unix, git-bash

I want to add a new blank line after every 50 words on several text files. I made this code, almost works, it create the new file with the same name, but doesn't make the parsing with the changes from main files. Can anyone give me a little help?

```
 $allfiles = Get-ChildItem c:\Folder1\*.txt
  foreach($onefile in $allfiles){
  $array = $file -split(" ")
        
  foreach($word in $array){
      $output += $word
      $count ++
      if($count%50 -eq 0){
          $output += "`r`n`r`n"
      }
      else{
          if ($word -ne $array[-1])  # check if last word no space needed
          {
              $output +=" "
          }
      }
  }
  $result = "result_" + $onefile.name 
      $output | out-file c:\Folder1\$result 
  }
```

Comment: Why there is a `bash` tag if it is just for `powershell` ?

Comment: just powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$allfiles = Get-ChildItem c:\Folder1\*.txt

foreach($onefile in $allfiles)
{
    $result=[system.collections.generic.list[string]]::new()
    
    $words=(cat $onefile) -split '\s'
    $z=49

    for($i=0;$i -lt $words.count;$i+=50)
    {
        $result.Add(($words[$i..$z] -join ' ').trim())
        $result.Add("`r`n")
        $z=$z+50
    }

    $result | out-file "c:\Folder1\result_$($onefile.name).txt"
}
```

Comment: np, glad to help. did it work? @HellenaCrainicu